# Assertion to check array contents for duplicate values

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I have an array `logic [254:0][7:0] array`. By design, this array must consist all values from 0 to 254 exactly once.

I want to write a SystemVerilog assertion to test it.

So far, I came up with something like this:

```
    logic update_array_d;
    bit [254:0] a_array_dup_mask;

    always_ff @(posedge clock, negedge arstn)
        if(!arstn) update_array_d <= 1'b0;
        else update_array_d <= update_array;

    always_comb begin
        a_array_dup_mask= '0;
        if(update_array_d) begin
            a_array_dup_mask= '1;
            for(int i=0; i<254; i++)
                a_array_dup_mask[array[i]] = 1'b0;
        end
    end
    UNIQUE_ARRAY: assert property (
        @(posedge clock) disable iff (!arstn)
        update_array_d |-> a_array_dup_mask == '0
    );
```

Is there a more elegant way to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine as long as it works for you and you find it easy to understand.

---

You could also consider this approach.

You declared `array` as a packed array.  Had you declared it as an *unpacked* array, such as:

```
logic [7:0] array [255];
```

then you would have been able to use the `unique` array method.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 7.12.1 *Array locator methods*.  But you would have also needed to declare an intermediate queue variable as well.  Whether this is more elegant is debatable.  Something along the lines of:

```
logic [7:0] array [255];
logic [7:0] q [$];
q = array.unique();
if (q.size() == $size(array)) // there are no duplicates in the array
```